# TypeError "cannot set properties of undefined" when Shuffling Array from Module

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, typeerror, shuffle

when I try to shuffle an array I get a `TypeError: "cannot set properties of undefined (setting '10')"` where 10 is the value of `randomNmbrArr[0]`. I have 2 other functions that I copied this code from that do work without any problems. I cant find the difference between the working code and the part that doesn't.

`let nmr` always logs a valid number between the range of 10 and 72. But for some reason `randomNmbrArr[nmr]` is undefined. Any idea's?

p.s: The code is running from a module but gives the same error in the main file. The array and function are declared before they are called in any way.

working code:

```js
let unicodeArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 65537; i++) {
  unicodeArr.push(i);
};

function randomNumber2() {
  let o = 0;
  let nmr2;
  while (++o < 65536) {
    nmr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (65536 + 1));
    [unicodeArr[nmr2], unicodeArr[0]] = [unicodeArr[0], unicodeArr[nmr2]];
  };
  return unicodeArr[0];
};
```

Code that does not work:

```js
let randomNmbrArr = [];

for (let i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
  randomNmbrArr.push(i);
}
console.log(randomNmbrArr)

function makeRandomNmbrs() {
  let k = 0;
  let nmr;
  while (++k < 62) {
    nmr = Math.floor(Math.random() * (62 + 1)) + 10;
    console.log(nmr);
    [randomNmbrArr[nmr], randomNmbrArr[0]] = [randomNmbrArr[0], randomNmbrArr[nmr]]; //TypeError at this line
    console.log(randomNmbrArr)
  }

}
```

Comment: It does not show an error to me?

Comment: Do you call `makeRandomNmbrs` from a place where the array has not yet been initialized (or has been initialized in parts only) ?

Comment: @collapsar It also does not show an error to me in JSfiddle. The code was in a module that I import, but to see if that was the problem I put it in the main file just under the import statements in the same order. ```makeRandomNmbrs``` is being called from an eventlistener by clicking a button on the bottom of the main file. p.s.: also when I call ```makeRandomNmbrs``` from below the code it gives the same error.

Comment: It works fine with me. You should share the rest of your code, **reduced to a minimal verifiable example**.